# Unit test a javascript function in an angular service using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Unit test a javascript function in an angular service using jasmine

**This is my angular service:**

```
angular.module("app.services").service("validationService", ["$q", function ($q) {

        this.validate = function (filter): ng.IPromise<any> {
            let defer = $q.defer();

            defer.resolve(validateOrder(filter.valA, filter.valB);

            return defer.promise;
        };

        function validateOrder = (valueA, valueB) {
            return valueA > valueB;
        };
    }]);
```

**This is my current unit test:**

```
"use strict";

describe("Service: validationService -> ", function () {
    // load the service"s module
    beforeEach(module("app.services"));

    var validationService;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        validationService = $injector.get("validationService");
    }));

    it("should call validateOrder and return false", function() {
        // Arrange
        var filter = {"valA": 10, "valB": 100};

        // Act and Assert
        expect(validationService.validateOrder(filter.valA, filter.valB)).toEqual(false);
    });

});
```

I want to test the function called: "validateOrder" within converting it to a this.validateOrder function.

How would I do this while keeping it as a function?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can test private functions without exposing them. Public function(functions on scope) you test should intern test private functions.

[How to test 'private' functions in an angular service with Karma and Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013335/how-to-test-private-functions-in-an-angular-service-with-karma-and-jasmine)